# Replace "Submit" button with "Flag" in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

Any type of flag when flagging post in the iOS app have "Flag" button:

> [image: Flag]

Except when you need a moderator intervention:

> [image: Submit]

I think this "Submit" button should be replaced with "Flag" button too for consistency.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)